# how can i convert fileStream to a blob to add it in sql table?

Tags: java

my database is like this : id(int),nomTournoi(varchar),nbr_equipe(int),dateTournoi(date),terrainTournoi(varchar),image(blob)
im trynig to add to my table the image but i can't get how to convert the file to blob
im trynig to convert it to fileInputStream but no way
if any one can give me a hint on how to do it
this is my function in my doc.java

```
public void ajouterTournoi(Tournoi t) {
    try {
    String requete = "INSERT INTO tournoi (nomTournoi,nbr_equipe,dateTournoi,terrainTournoi,image)"
    + "VALUES ('"+t.getNomTournoi()+"','"+t.getNbr_equipe()+"','"+t.getDateTournoi()+"','"+t.getTerrainTournoi()+"','"+t.getImage()+"')";
        Statement st = MyConnection.getInstance().getCnx()
                .createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(requete);
        System.out.println("Tournoi ajoutée");
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

and this is the function on the controller

```
private void ajouterTournoi(ActionEvent event) {

        /// SAUVEGARDE DANS LA BD
        String nomT = nomTournoi.getText();
        String nomTerrain = terrain.getValue();
        Integer nbr_Equipe = nbrEquipe.getValue();
        LocalDate dateT = dateTournoi.getValue();
        try {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
        
        Tournoi p = new Tournoi(14, nomT, nbr_Equipe, dateT, nomTerrain,fileInput);          
        TournoiCRUD pcd = new TournoiCRUD();
        pcd.ajouterTournoi(p);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "image ajouté");            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tournoi ajouté");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddTournoiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged javafx?

Comment: @James_D im using javafx interfaces and controller

Comment: But that has nothing to do with your question, right?

Comment: Code written in French significantly reduces your chances of getting a good answer since fewer people understand it.

Comment: A tip for your future submissions: Focus on what is important. Show us what fields "Turnoi" has, mention that you are using JDBC to access your database (not JPA or something). Don't add stuff that is not necessary to answer (we don't need the UI part for the DB access). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First off, you **really should use a prepared statement**, because the way you build DB statements is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
Secondly, I think [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) are anyway the only way to insert blobs.

```
PreparedStatement statement = MyConnection.getInstance().getCnx()
    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tournoi (nomTournoi,nbr_equipe,dateTournoi,terrainTournoi,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
// I don't know what types you have here
statement.setString(1, t.getNomTournoi());
// Add your other arguments here
statement.set(5, t.getImage());
```